# Is it possible without react-native to gather geolocation information in a background task for Android and/or iOS?

Tags: android, ios, geolocation, react-native

Is it possible in react-native to execute a background task with monitoring GPS position (without running the whole app in the background), even if the phone is locked?
I want to show some information (notification) onscreen when the phone will be in some position.

I need to declare the subject of a project in my studies, but I don't know if it's possible to implement this functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It most certainly is... if you have only one given position (Or fewer than 20 positions) what you'd be best using is CoreLocation's [geofencing](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/monitoring_the_user_s_proximity_to_geographic_regions) APIs!

You can set up a region like so:

```
if CLLocationManager.isMonitoringAvailable(for: CLCircularRegion.self) {
    // Register the region.
    let region = CLCircularRegion(
        center: center, 
        radius: maxDistance, identifier: identifier
    )
    region.notifyOnEntry = true

    locationManager.startMonitoring(for: region)
}
```

(Assuming you have already requested and checked the user's location permissions)!

Your app will then get launched in the background whenever a region monitoring event occurs, so you must make sure to setup a new `CLLocationManager` and give it a delegate to receive the updates in your `application(_application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions)` function!

You can then use the delegate callbacks to trigger a local notification.

There is a slight caveat here, that this won't work if the user has disabled background app refresh for your app!

Luck, there's already a react-native library that allows you to setup these regions: https://github.com/martijndeh/react-native-region-monitor. Unfortunately I do think it will launch your JavaScript app fully (in the background of course) when a notification comes through, but that's not too big an issue.

There may also be info on the GitHub provided for how to implement this on Android too!